# How to send extra data with Image?

Tags: html, image, http, web, metadata

In case of image galleries, the image contains a title , description and other information.
I want to transmit every information (along with image data) in the response. Is this possible, in single HTTP response.
The reason I am asking is that, in database, in a single query, everything can be returned viz. the image path, its title, description etc. So, will it not be beneficial to return everything in a single response.
Currently, I am able to just fetch the image path and name (written as imagepath) from database and return the image to the user. 
My (usual fetch, read and output file) Backend code (Php):

```
$img_id=$_GET['id'];
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','mydb');
$stmt= mysqli_prepare($con,'select imagepath,description,title from images where imgid=?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s',$img_id)
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $imgpath,$desc,$title);
if (!mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) return ;
//single result
if (file_exists($imgpath)) 
{
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($imgpath));
    readfile($file);
}
```

// Currently, I am unable to send desc and title via this. Is there a way to send them in a single response?
Also, is there a way to retrieve them in the browser side using javascript?

Comment: You need to be much more specific in your question. Post relevant code showing what attempts you've made. As it currently stands, your question is too broad to answer

Answer (score 1):

The "X-" prefix is for non-standard headers.

So you might just send your own headers with information you need:

```
header('X-Image-Title: '.$title);
```

UPDATE:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648

So just use it without the `X-` prefix ;)